# How can I prevent this from looping?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a button which I press to jump. My problem right now is once I press this button once my Player just keeps jumping forever. But I want to make it so that I have to press the jump button again once I hit the ground. This is my current code:

```
  public void onButtonJump()
    {
         if (controller.isGrounded )
        {

            verticalVelocity = -gravity * Time.deltaTime;

            {

                verticalVelocity = jumpForce;
                animator.SetBool("is_in_air", true);
                jump.Play();


            }

        }
        else
        {
            animator.SetBool("is_in_air", false);
            verticalVelocity -= gravity * Time.deltaTime;
        }
    }
```

How do i prevent this from looping and do so that I have to press the button again once I am grounded?

Comment: Where are you calling onButtonJump() , Need some more code for this.

Comment: and where is `controller.isGrounded` set?

Comment: onButtonJump() gets called when I click a canvas ui button in the game so it's on the onClick()

the controller.isgrounded checks wether or not i am on the ground in my game. that part of it works it can tell wether I'm on the ground layer of my game or not. The controller is on my Player.

Comment: Silly question: why not just explicitly set `IsGrounded = false` at the same point at which you set `animator.SetBool("is_in_air", true);` -- I have a good feeling that might fix it for you...You have two different boolean values that seem to represent the same concept but expressed inverserly: `IsGrounded` and `is_in_air`) -- beware, this type of construct seems simple but can easily become very confusing.

Comment: That didn't work. `the animator.SetBool("is_in_air", true);` is just setting the animation is_in_air to true so it plays my jump animation.

Comment: That's not what David meant. He stated you should use `controller.isGrounded` and set that to false along with your animation. You're only checking for it and you never set it.

Comment: I tried setting `controller.isGrounded = false;` it didn't work for me.

Comment: As Jay said, we need to see how you're calling `onButtonJump()`

Comment: Also, make sure that `isGrounded` is actually turning false when you jump!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't do 'gravity' under a button, only do it in FixedUpdate ('physics frame' update):

```
void FixedUpdate() {
    if ( controller.isGrounded )
        verticalVelocity = 0;
    else
        verticalVelocity -= gravity * Time.deltaTime;

    // Apply velocity to transform here
}

void onButtonJump() {
    if (controller.isGrounded ) {
        verticalVelocity = jumpVelocity;
        // Play animation and sound here
    }
}
```